# Не удаляется мутекс

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mutex

Создается мутекс `HANDLE hHande = CreateMutex(0, 0, "mut_name");`

После чего `OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, 0, "mut_name")` начинает возвращать указатель на него.

Каким образом можно удалить созданный мутекс, чтобы `OpenMutex` перестал возвращать указатель на него? `CloseHandle(hHande)` и `ReleaseMutex(hHande)` не помогают.

Comment: Сколько раз вы вызывали `CloseHandle`?

Comment: Да, вызывался 1 раз.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CreateMutex` "открывает" свежесозданный mutex. `OpenMutex` тоже "открывает" существующий mutex.

Если вы хотите, чтобы mutex был уничтожен, вам надо "закрыть" через `CloseHandle` все "открытия". То есть вызовы `CreateMutex` и `OpenMutex` вкупе требуют *два* последующих вызова `CloseHandle`, чтобы mutex уничтожился

```
HANDLE hHandle = CreateMutex(0, 0, "mut_name");
// Открытие. Счетчик открытий: 1

HANDLE h = OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, 0, "mut_name");
// Открытие. Счетчик открытий: 2
CloseHandle(h);
// Закрытие. Счетчик открытий: 1. Mutex все еще существует

CloseHandle(hHandle);
// Закрытие. Счетчик открытий: 0. Mutex уничтожен

h = OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, 0, "mut_name");
// Получаем NULL
```